# Como apagar um item especifico de uma ListView?

Tags: android, string, listview, android-adapter

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida: Tenho uma `ListView`, em que seu *adapter* está esclarecido na mesma *activity* e o conteúdo do *adapter* (as *strings*) estão em uma outra classe, em um outro pacote. Como faço para apagar um item específico da `ListView`, no código mesmo, sem interação com o usuário? (por exemplo, uma atualização do aplicativo em que um item não irá mais aparecer).

**No caso em que estou estudando, o usuário irá clicar em um item da `listView`, e um texto dentro da activity será preenchido com a string que está na `otherClass.lista` e dependendo da posição (position) clicada, irá aparecer um texto diferente.**

**EDITADO**

Segue a ação do clique na ListView:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
listView.setAdapter(new listAdapter(this));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

                nome.setText(otherClass.string.get(position));

            }
});
```

Segue o Adapter que estou usando:

```
public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<String> lug;
    public Typeface fonte;

    public listAdapter(Context context) {



        lug = otherClass.string;


        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lug.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lug[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView title = new TextView(context);     
            title.setText(lug.get(position));
            title.setTextSize(18);

        return title;
    }

}
```

Agora segue o Array na classe que está em outro pacote

```
public class otherClass {

public static ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();{
    string.add("primeiro item");
    string.add("Segundo item");
}
}
```

O problema atual é que não está sendo impresso os itens do ArrayList acima... e gostaria de saber (quando conseguir imprimir os itens) como apagar os itens.

A intenção, como segue as imagens, seria que na `otherClass` ter os itens que irão aparecer na `listView` e clicando em algum item, aparecerá as respectivas informações do item clicado (estes declarados na mesma classe para não ficar confuso tudo separado). Mais itens serão adicionados a cada atualização do aplicativo, então precisa ser um modo dinâmico e organizado. Ideias? (já que Strings não parece ser uma boa forma)

[image: Como quero que apareça a lista de itens 1][image: Clicando em um dos itens anteriores, aparecerá outros itens, carregados naquela mesma classe "otherClass"]

Comment: Acho que você quer que seu `getItem(position)` retorne `lug[position]` e não `position`.

Comment: @Piovezan: 'position' é uma variável global, sendo referência para várias outras 'activities'. No caso, position tem a mesma função do lug[position], pois são os mesmos números sempre. (caso eu tenha entendido o que você quis dizer)

Comment: Um adapter é uma classe que intermedia o acesso da `ListView` à fonte de dados, que pode ser um array, um cursor de banco de dados, etc. O método `getItem(position)` tem que retornar um item dentro dessa fonte de dados que esteja na posição correspondente ao parâmetro `position`. Portanto, se a sua fonte de dados é uma array ou uma ArrayList, que já são naturalmente ordenados, o seu método `getItem(position)` deve retornar `meuArray[position]` ou `minhaLista.get(position)`, que representam itens dessas fontes de dados na posição em questão.

Comment: Complementando: a posição nunca vai ser o mesmo que o item contido nessa posição, a não ser que você tenha um array de inteiros e o valor de cada item corresponda à posição em que o mesmo se encontra no array. Por isso não entendo o que você quer dizer com position ser o mesmo que lug[position], até porque você está lidando com strings e não inteiros. Por acaso você quer dizer que os itens do array são "0", "1", "2", etc.? Nesse caso `getItem(position)` deveria retornar `String.valueOf(position)` e não `position`. Mas para todos os efeitos, retornar `lug[position]` faz mais sentido.

Comment: @Piovezan: Eu atualizei o código com mais informações. Utilizei lug[position]. No meu string, os itens eles são identificados pela posição mesmo: "primeiro item" = 0, "segundo item" = 1, e etc.. dê uma olhada por favor. O que coloquei como atualização é o modo original com que fiz o aplicativo, rodou bonito mas a única coisa é que não sei apagar os itens, que talvez como disseram não há como se for declarado como string[], correto?

Comment: Veja meu comentário abaixo da resposta.

Comment: Aconselho a reformular sua pergunta. Colocar o código de cada classe e mostrar exatamente onde está o erro, está muito confuso do jeito que está, mesmo acompanhando os comentários.

Comment: @LucasSantos: Reformulei, está menos confuso? Tentei dar uma enxugada..

Comment: Coloque o código da sua activity. Está melhorando. Vou te ajudar.

Comment: @LucasSantos: Esqueci de colocar como declarei o adapter e a ListView.. mas é praticamente apenas isso minha activity..

Comment: @GH_ Ok, Vou tentar postar uma solução mesmo sem o código da activity. Aguarde que estou postando...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos lá @GH_ veja se isso ajuda.

Cria uma classe chamada Outros, essa classe irá persistir os dados que você quer para um determinado objeto, vamos supor que seja uma pessoa, carro, ou qualquer coisa. No seu caso irá persistir duas Strings: primeiro item e segunto item.

```
/**
 * Classe que irá persistir dados de um objeto para ser usado em uma lista de Strings.
 */
public class Outros {
    private String primeiroItem;
    private String segundoItem;

    public Outros( String primeiroItem, String segundoItem ) {
        this.primeiroItem = primeiroItem;
        this.segundoItem = segundoItem;
    }

    public String getPrimeiroItem() {
        return primeiroItem;
    }

    public void setPrimeiroItem( String primeiroItem ) {
        this.primeiroItem = primeiroItem;
    }

    public String getSegundoItem() {
        return segundoItem;
    }

    public void setSegundoItem( String segundoItem ) {
        this.segundoItem = segundoItem;
    }
}
```

Seu adapter pode ficar da seguinta forma:

```
public class MeuCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /** Lista de objetos outros, contendo duas Strings. */
    private List<Outros> listOutros;
    /** Contexto usado para acessar recursos de string */
    private Context contexto;

    /**
     * Metodo construtor que recebe o contexto e uma lista de objetos instrumentos para popular o ListView personalizado.
     *
     * @param contexto Contexto uasdo para acessar o recurso de layout.
     * @param listOutros  Lista de objetos da representacao de cada item de lista (linha do ListView).
     */
    public MeuCustomAdapter( Context contexto, List<Outros> listOutros ) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.listOutros = listOutros;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listOutros.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem( int position ) {
        return listOutros.get( position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position ) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Chamado toda vez que e necessario mostrar um item da ListView.
     *
     * @param position    A posicao do item de ListView.
     * @param convertView O elemento View que representa o item de ListView.
     * @param parent      Elemento pai do elemento view.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        TextView textViewTitle = new TextView( contexto );
        // Aqui é definido como texto do TextView o primeiro item do objeto Outros.
        textViewTitle.setText( listOutros.get( position ).getPrimeiroItem() );
        textViewTitle.setTextSize(18);

        // Para exibir o item você tem que retornar uma VIEW e não uma String.
        return textViewTitle;
    }
}
```

Na Sua activity você faz assim:

```
    ListView listView = findViewById( R.id.meuListView );

    Outros outros1 = new Outros( "Outros 1", "Item 1" );
    Outros outros2 = new Outros( "Outros 2", "Item 2" );
    Outros outros3 = new Outros( "Outros 3", "Item 3" );

    List<Outros> listOutros = new ArrayList<Outros>();
    listOutros.add( outros1 );
    listOutros.add( outros2 );
    listOutros.add( outros3 );

    MeuCustomAdapter meuCustomAdapter = new MeuCustomAdapter( getAplicationContext(), listOutros );
    listView.setAdapter( meuCustomAdapter );
```

Não sei se vai ajudar, você tem que dar uma estudada a mais em Listas, adapters, padrão ViewHolder...

---

**EDITATADA**
: E para apagar um item específico do ListView basta fazer assim:

Para remover um item de um ArrayList você tem as seguintes opções:

1. `seuArrayList.clear()` - Remove todos os elementos do array deixando-o vazio;
2. `seuArrayList.remove(index)` - Remove o objeto na posição especificada na lista;
3. `seuArrayList.remove(Object)` - Remove a instância do objeto especificado se ele está contido.

Comment: Como eu faria pra colocar esse arrayList em outra classe? Por exemplo, ao invés de criar os itens na activity, fazer uma classe que tenha os itens, e na activity apenas fazer a referencia. Tem como?

Comment: Pode sim. Por acaso você já tem algum código da outra classe para eu tentar ajudar a partir do seu código? Ou ainda não tem o código?

Comment: Eu havia tentado, mas acabei desistindo e apagando, sendo assim, tenho que começar do nada :(

Comment: Para criar esse `ArrayList` em outra classe é da mesma forma que criou na `Activity`. Para recuperar este `ArrayList` em sua `Activity` é só você ter um objeto dessa sua classe e chamar algum método `getMeyArray()` que retorna o seu `ArrayList`.

Comment: Seguindo os mesmos padrões da sua resposta, o `listOutros.add( outros1 )` fica na classe criada, ou na activity?

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi que você quer fazer, fica na classe criada.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, mas provavelmente só semana que vem eu venha com respostas, pois terei provas essa semana. Sendo assim, te aviso qualquer coisa. Valeu

Comment: LucasSantos: Tive um tempo aqui e testei, deu certinho cara, muito obrigado mais uma vez hahaha

Comment: @GH_ de nada. rsrsrs.

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta nova, baseada nessa resposta.. as coisas estão meio obscuras por lá e gostaria de saber se você tem alguma ideia. Agradeço antecipadamente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25530/como-modificar-e-salvar-o-novo-item-modificado-de-uma-listview/25554#25554

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar [`adapter.remove()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) e em seguida chamar o método [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) para ter as alterações refletidas na *Listview*.

Veja:

```java
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(index)); // Índice do item a ser deletado
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: :no meu caso, seria: List.remove(List.getItem(position))?

Comment: Remover elementos do seu adapter só irá funcionar se você usar um `ArrayList` ao invés de um `String[]` (array de strings), porque o número de elementos precisa ser variável para você conseguir remover um elemento contido no objeto que sua referência `lug` irá guardar.

Comment: @Piovezan: Eu editei o código, como eu mudaria a minha string na outra classe para um arrayList parecido com aquele formato e que de para apagar?

Comment: @GH_ Na outra classe você declara por exemplo `ArrayList<String> minhaLista = new ArrayList<String>();` e adiciona strings a ela fazendo `minhaLista.add(umaString);`

Comment: @Piovezan: Eu fiz isso, mas na activity, quando eu chamo o `Array`, aparece o erro: "**The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>**". Obs: Eu chamo na activity do modo outraClasse.minhaLista[position]. Alguma dica?

Comment: Para acessar os itens de uma `ArrayList` você deve usar `minhaLista.get(position);`

Comment: @DBX8: está atualizado. Por favor, dê uma olhada.

Comment: @Piovezan: Eu fiz as alterações necessárias, mas não foi impresso nada na tela.

Comment: @GH_ Por favor poste todo o código necessário na pergunta para entendermos o que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: @GH_ Como foi falado antes, usando array não vai ser possível alterar o número de strings da lista. Faça as alterações que foram citadas para usar ArrayList. Caso não apareça nada como você falou que aconteceu, poste o código contendo essas alterações. Foi esse o código que eu havia solicitado.

Comment: @Piovezan: atualizado e encontrado outro erro no setAdapter. Aquele erro de não mostrar a lista foi equivoco meu. peço perdão pela perda de tempo. Estou a procura do erro por aqui

Comment: @piovezan: encontrei o erro e consertei, mas vi que realmente ainda não mostra os itens..