# Como modificar e salvar o novo item modificado de uma listView?

Tags: android, listview

Gostaria de saber como faço para salvar várias posições de uma listView. Como exemplo, deixar o usuário marcar como favorito certos itens da lista.

Não sei o que seria útil para obter uma resposta eficiente, então irei postar algumas partes importantes que exemplificam o funcionamento do meu código:

**ListView no fragmento**

```
 ItensAdapter meuCustomAdapter = new ItensAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(),
                    Lista.Itens.setItens());
            lista.setAdapter(meuCustomAdapter);

            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                        //Aqui eu iria salvar mudando a cor de fundo do item
                }

            });
```

**Adaptador**

```
public class ItensAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Info> informacoes;

private Context contexto;

private Typeface fonte;


public ItensAdapter(Context contexto, List<Info> informacoes) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.informacoes = informacoes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return informacoes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return informacoes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView titulos = new TextView(contexto);

    titulos.setTypeface(fonte);
    titulos.setTextSize(18);
    titulos.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    titulos.setPadding(8, 48, 8, 48);
    titulos.setText(informacoes.get(position).getNome());

    return titulos;
}
}
```

**Classe modificada Info**

```
 public class Info {

private String nome;

public Info(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;

}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

**Classe Lista**

```
 public class Lista {

static Context context;

// TODO

public static class Itens {

    public final static Info ob1 = new Info(
            "Item 1");
    public final static Info ob2 = new Info(
            "Item 2");
    public final static Info ob3 = new Info(
            "Item 3");
    public final static Info ob4 = new Info(
            "Item 4");
    public final static Info ob5 = new Info(
            "Item 5");

    public static List<Info> setItens() {
        final List<Info> itens = new ArrayList<Info>();

        itens.add(ob1);
        itens.add(ob2);
        itens.add(ob3);
        itens.add(ob4);
        itens.add(ob5);


        return itens;
    }

}
```

Comment: como você quer salvar esses itens da lista? Você quer salvar esses itens de tal maneira que você saia da aplicação e, quando entrar novamente, os itens salvos estejam lá? Vi que ela é uma lista de objetos Info contendo apenas nome correto? Por favor, tente explicar melhor e responder a essas perguntas que fiz para eu tentar te ajudar, caso contrário, não vou conseguir pois não entendi muito bem o seu problema.

Comment: @LucasSantos eu quero salvar dessa maneira mesmo, de modo que eu saia da aplicação e o item escolhido como favorito ainda esteja lá marcado. Por enquanto a Info tem apenas nomes, pois está como de estudo, ainda irei adicionar email e telefone.

Comment: Acho que entendi, você tem uma lista, nessa lista cada item tem um nome e um CheckBox para marcá-lo como favorito ou não. Se você marcar como favorito, ao sair do app e voltar novamente, ao carregar a lista, os checkbox's devem estar marcados. É isto mesmo ou eu me enganei? Se for isso mesmo vou tentar elaborar uma resposta para você depois, não agora no momento, assim que possível.

Comment: @LucasSantos eu iria preferir que fosse com um longo clique mesmo

Comment: Ok. Entendi. Ele dá um longo clique e realça a cor de fundo para saber que está como favorito.

Comment: @LucasSantos Isso mesmo

Comment: você pode tentar seguir o que diz esse link: http://tuohuang.info/android-listview-remember-selection-and-set-default-selection/#.U8hWJvldXDQ Para realçar o item selecionado. Para salvar o estado recomendo a utilizar o SharedPreferences como o amigo Jorge B. disse.

Comment: Então Lucas, minha dificuldade está sendo na lógica do sharedPreferences. Pois na teoria, eu teria que fazer um array de integers... Ou não?

Comment: Acho que SharedPreferences não salva array. Você tem que visualizar os métodos da classe SharedPreferences e ver o que pode salvar. O realce do fundo você já conseguiu fazer?

Comment: @LucasSantos sim, o fundo é tranquilo, o problema é fazer com que o código recorde as posições

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria recupera os itens através do método [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891026/get-clicked-item-from-listview) do [lisView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) e gravar  os dados em um arquivo [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) do Android

```
 String favorito = listView.getSelectedItem();

 SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString(KEY, favorito);
 editor.commit();
```

Depois de salvo precisaria apenas recuperar as informações no arquivo Shared Preference e carregar na lista.

Comment: Essa forma não conhecia. Isso funciona?

Comment: Mas aí, se eu salvar a string da lista e depois recuperar ela, não iria haver duplicação? Não há como salvar apenas a posição e nela tomar referência na lista?

Comment: Da sim, ao invés de salvar a string do favorito, salva a posição `int position = listView.getIdItemSelected();`

Comment: ta, mas minha lista tem mais de um item.. como eu iria salvar no shared preferences 3 itens, e depois recuperá-los em um `onResume()` por exemplo? aí teria que ser um Array de Integers... entende onde quero chegar?

Comment: O ideal seria uma tabela na base de dados chamada de "favorito" lá vc recuperava o id da posicao do listView. Mas se quiser fazer no prefence também dá. `editor.putInt(KEY, favorito); editor.putInt(KEY, favorito2); editor.putInt(KEY, favorito3);`

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faço nesse caso é ter duas listas:

- uma lista dos itens todos que aparecem na `listView`;
- outra **lista com os itens selecionados** (`lista_selec`).

Depois sempre que clico na `CheckBox` (*true*) adiciono o item a `lista_selec`.

Ou seja ai no teu  `onItemClick` é só verificar para cada objeto da posição selecionada se está ativo ou não.
Se estiver ativo, como clicaste vai passar a desativo (removes da `lista_selec`), se estiver desativo ao clicares fica ativo (adicionas a `lista_selec`).

A `lista_selec` só serve mesmo para manter o registo dos campos selecionados para depois gravar na BD. Era isso que querias certo?

Comment: Então eu teria que ter duas listas em um layout, e a lista de selecionados irá ficar a parte?

Comment: Não, tem já a tua lista `lista` certo? depois terias uma lista NORMAL, com os itens selecionados, para gravar na BD.

Comment: Desculpe meu caro, mas não consegui compreender sua resposta.

Comment: A tua lista: `lista.setAdapter(meuCustomAdapter);` é uma lista de que? Mostra-me a declaração dessa lista.

Comment: Porque não usa um `Set` com os índices do itens selecionados. Seria eficiente usar um `HashSet` pra validar se um determinado item no `Adapter` esta selecionado. Outra sugestão é olhar o codigo fonte do `ListView`, ele trata seleção (choiceMode), e pra isso ele usa um `SparseArray` com os índices.

Comment: @Wakim eu pensei em fazer isso, mas aí como eu relacionaria a posição com o booleano?

Comment: A chaves do `SparseArray` (usar o metodo `keyAt` para saber a posição) seriam as posições do Adapter que estão selecionadas. Eu fiz isso já, mas no momento não consigo montar uma resposta.

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil teres uma lista de itens selecionados no teu código. Sempre que alguém clicar no checkbox, ou adiciona na lista_de_itens_selecionados, ou retira, conforme seja true ou false a checkbox.

Comment: Acho que entendi.. e no caso, eu comparo as duas listas, e os itens iguais eu o identificaria como selecionado. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Vê a minha resposta agora, editei.